# Converting tick data to OHLC bars using R

Tags: r

How can I convert tick data into OHLC data using R? I have seen a couple of examples on here but the issue I am having is converting the actual times for the individual time stamps. For example the very first time stamp is `2013-07-29 15:30:00`.

> x <- read.delim(header=TRUE, stringsAsFactor=FALSE,"http://hopey.netfonds.no/tradedump.php?date=20130729&paper=AAPL.O&csv_format=txt")
>
> xx <- xts(x[,c(2:3)], as.POSIXct(x[,1], "UTC", "%Y%m%dT%H%M%S"))
>
> to.period(xx,"seconds",5)

Comment: What have you tried? I don't understand how the first time stamp could possibly be on 2013-07-26. And your problem isn't how to convert tick to OHLC... it's how to convert the timestamp into an actual date-time object (e.g. `POSIXct`).

Comment: you are right i missed copied the tick data... the first time stamp should be 2013-06-14 15:30:00... i am new to R, but from what i have seen here, i am suppose to use xts ? & to.minute

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich also here is a link, that you have also helped on i believe? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8830472/create-an-ohlc-series-from-ticker-data-using-r

Comment: I would strongly suggest using `read.delim()` instead of `read.csv()` -- it appears that the data you are pulling down are tab- rather than comma-separated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use `to.period` (or one of the wrappers) once you've created an xts object.  To properly convert `time` to POSIXct, you have to specify the correct format (including the "T").

```
xx <- xts(x[,-1], as.POSIXct(x[,1], "UTC", "%Y%m%dT%H%M%S"))
to.period(xx, "seconds")
```

Also note that you should specify the timezone the `time` column was recorded in.  I specified it as `"UTC"`, since I don't know what timezone to use.

Comment: works well in converting the time, but i get an error message when i add: to.period (xx, "seconds") as such...

Comment: Warning message:
timezone of object (UTC) is different than current timezone (). 
> to.period(xx,"seconds")
Error in na.omit.xts(x) : unsupported type

Comment: My code works fine on the data in this Q/A. You didn't provide a reproducible example of your data, so I suspect there's an issue with your actual data.  My guess is that's it's being coerced to character because xts/zoo objects can only contain a single data type. If you want me to do more than guess, provide a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/271616).

Comment: I'm not going to do your work for you. Simply providing the data is not a reproducible example. You should edit your question to read the data from the URL in your previous comment, then show what you tried and how it differed from what you expected.

Comment: i tried pulling the data straight from the source as shown on the original question.... to show what i have done. "x" contains no data... i dont know if that helps

Comment: @user2634864 try `read.delim` instead of `read.csv`, then `xx <- xts(x[,c(2:3)], as.POSIXct(x[,1], "UTC", "%Y%m%dT%H%M%S"))`

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich That did the trick, thank you so much. if i have data stored in Excel but save it as .csv & import it into Rstudio would i have to write                                                         `x <- read.csv(file,header=TRUE, stringsAsFactor=FALSE)`

Comment: If @JoshuaUlrich's answer solved your problem, you are encouraged (not required) to click the check-mark next to the answer to accept it ...

Comment: while you're at it, you might as well edit your original question to use `read.delim()`, so future readers don't get confused/have to dig into the comments to find out how to get Josh's answer to work.