# Convert data to OHLC (Open, High, Low, Close) in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts, finance, quantitative-finance

Similar to [create an OHLC data from Date, time, price using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24780823/create-an-ohlc-data-from-date-time-price-using-c-sharp), how does one take the theory of converting basic trade data to OHLC (or Open, High, Low, Close) and apply it to this distinct case?

```
var data = [{
    "tid": 283945,
    "date": 1384934366,
    "amount": "0.08180000",
    "price": "501.30"
}, {
    "tid": 283947,
    "date": 1384934066,
    "amount": "0.06110000",
    "price": "490.66"
},
...
];

function convertToOHLC(data) {
    // What goes here?
}
convertToOHLC(data);
```

Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/5dfjhnLw/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a working function for converting the data to OHLC:

```
function convertToOHLC(data) {
    data.sort((a, b) => d3.ascending(a.date, b.date));
    var result = [];
    var format = d3.timeFormat("%Y-%m-%d");
    data.forEach(d => d.date = format(new Date(d.date * 1000)));
    var allDates = [...new Set(data.map(d => d.date))];
    allDates.forEach(d => {
        var tempObject = {};
        var filteredData = data.filter(e => e.date === d);
        tempObject.date = d;
        tempObject.open = filteredData[0].price;
        tempObject.close = filteredData[filteredData.length - 1].price;
        tempObject.high = d3.max(filteredData, e => e.price);
        tempObject.low = d3.min(filteredData, e => e.price);
        result.push(tempObject);
    });
    return result;
};
```

Here is your updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mg9v89r2/

### Step by step explanation:

First, we sort the original data array by the dates:

```
data.sort((a, b) => d3.ascending(a.date, b.date));
```

That's an important step when we deal with `open` and `close` later.

After that, we convert the milliseconds to dates, as strings:

```
var format = d3.timeFormat("%Y-%m-%d");
data.forEach(d => d.date = format(new Date(d.date * 1000)));
```

Doing this, we can filter all objects belonging to a given day. First, we create an array with all different days in your data:

```
var allDates = [...new Set(data.map(d => d.date))];
```

For each day of that array, we will call a function that will populate an empty array, named `results`:

```
allDates.forEach(d => {
    var tempObject = {};
    var filteredData = data.filter(e => e.date === d);
    tempObject.date = d;
    tempObject.open = filteredData[0].price;
    tempObject.close = filteredData[filteredData.length - 1].price;
    tempObject.high = d3.max(filteredData, e => e.price);
    tempObject.low = d3.min(filteredData, e => e.price);
    result.push(tempObject);
});
```

In the above `forEach`, we create an empty object, and for each day in our `allDates` array, we filter the data:

```
var filteredData = data.filter(e => e.date === d);
```

And populate an temporary object with it:

```
var tempObject = {};
tempObject.date = d;
tempObject.open = filteredData[0].price;
tempObject.close = filteredData[filteredData.length - 1].price;
tempObject.high = d3.max(filteredData, e => e.price);
tempObject.low = d3.min(filteredData, e => e.price);
```

After each iteration, we push that temporary object into `results`:

```
result.push(tempObject);
```

Finally, we return `results`.

That huge data array in your fiddle, surprisingly, has only 2 days of data.

Comment: This is remarkable stuff Gerardo! And your explanation makes so much sense as well. Thank you so much!

Comment: Hi! I'm attempting running your fiddle against some actual data (a CSV of all bitcoin trades ever in my country): https://jsfiddle.net/askhflajsf/mg9v89r2/5/ -- any chance you can tell what went wrong?

Comment: Please, post is as a question and I can have a look at it.

Comment: Cool, thanks. Here it is: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46420571/convert-csv-to-ohlc-open-high-low-close-in-javascript

Comment: can you please also hint how we could do for other intervals as well? (Suppose I have 1 min ticker data, I would typically want 5 min ohlc, 60 min ohlc, 1 day ohlc, 1 week ohlc, 1 month ohlc etc). I suppose key is in that ```allDates``` line?!