# Convert CSV to OHLC (Open, High, Low, Close) in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, csv, d3.js

I'm attempting to use the script in [Convert data to OHLC (Open, High, Low, Close) in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42064703/convert-data-to-ohlc-open-high-low-close-in-javascript) to convert some chart data to OHLC. The only thing is that my data differs a bit from the original (http://api.bitcoincharts.com/v1/csv/localbtcDKK.csv.gz - showing all bitcoin trades ever done in Denmark), so how would I have to go about modifying the code?

**Original data**

```
var data = [{"tid": 283945, "date": 1384934366, "amount": "0.08180000", "price": "501.30"}, {"tid": 283947, "date": 1384934066, "amount": "0.06110000", "price": "490.66"}, ...];
```

**New data**

```
// CSV format: UNIX timestamp, price, amount traded
// http://api.bitcoincharts.com/v1/csv/localbtcDKK.csv.gz
var data = `1366383202,748.680000000000,1.000000000000
1366471506,777.440000000000,2.700000000000
1368121200,685.740000000000,2.187400000000
...`
```

Since it's CSV I've included [jquery-csv](https://github.com/evanplaice/jquery-csv/) for turning the data into an array. Here's my current code (https://jsfiddle.net/askhflajsf/mg9v89r2/5/):

```
// CSV format: UNIX timestamp, price, amount traded
// http://api.bitcoincharts.com/v1/csv/localbtcDKK.csv.gz

var data = `1366383202,748.680000000000,1.000000000000
1366471506,777.440000000000,2.700000000000
1368121200,685.740000000000,2.187400000000
1375783458,619.500000000000,1.000000000000
...`

function convertToOHLC(data) {
    data.sort((a,b)=>d3.ascending(a.date, b.date));
    var result = [];
    var format = d3.timeFormat("%Y-%m-%d");
    data.forEach(d=>d.date = format(new Date(d.date*1000)));
    var allDates = [...new Set(data.map(d=>d.date))];
    allDates.forEach(d=>{
        var tempObject = {};
        var filteredData = data.filter(e=>e.date === d);
        tempObject.date = d;
        tempObject.open = filteredData[0].price;
        tempObject.close = filteredData[filteredData.length-1].price;
        tempObject.high = d3.max(filteredData, e=>e.price);
        tempObject.low = d3.min(filteredData, e=>e.price);
        result.push(tempObject);
    })
  return result
}

// Parse multi-line CSV string into a 2D array
// https://github.com/evanplaice/jquery-csv

var dataArray = $.csv.toArrays(data);

// jquery-csv's arrays are made up of strings, but we need them to be numbers

// Trim whitespace and then convert to Number

var dataArrayNumbers = dataArray.map(row => row.map(el => Number(el.trim())));

console.log(convertToOHLC(dataArrayNumbers));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most important thing you have to do is adding **headers** to that data. Like this:

```
var data = `date,price,amount
1366383202,748.680000000000,1.000000000000
1366471506,777.440000000000,2.700000000000
//etc...
```

Without the headers, none of those properties will work.

Also, you don't need jQuery here. You can simply use D3:

```
var parsedArray = d3.csvParse(data)
```

If, for whatever reason, you cannot change your data to add the headers, you can add then in the code:

```
var headers = ["date", "price", "amount"];
var parsedArray = d3.csvParse(headers + "\n" + data)
```

Here is the demo with those changes:

```js
var csv = `date,price,amount
1366383202,748.680000000000,1.000000000000
1366471506,777.440000000000,2.700000000000
1368121200,685.740000000000,2.187400000000
1375783458,619.500000000000,1.000000000000`;

var originalData = d3.csvParse(csv)

function convertToOHLC(data) {
    data.sort((a,b)=>d3.ascending(a.date, b.date));
    var result = [];
    var format = d3.timeFormat("%Y-%m-%d");
    data.forEach(d=>d.date = format(new Date(d.date*1000)));
    var allDates = [...new Set(data.map(d=>d.date))];
    allDates.forEach(d=>{
        var tempObject = {};
        var filteredData = data.filter(e=>e.date === d);
        tempObject.date = d;
        tempObject.open = filteredData[0].price;
        tempObject.close = filteredData[filteredData.length-1].price;
        tempObject.high = d3.max(filteredData, e=>e.price);
        tempObject.low = d3.min(filteredData, e=>e.price);
        result.push(tempObject);
    })
  return result
}

console.log(convertToOHLC(originalData))
```

```html
<script src="//d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Much obliged! Goes to show how modular and well-written your code is the way it can easily adapt to any situation. Have a great day!

Comment: No worries. Remember: try to avoid mixing jQuery and D3 like the plague! You don't need it and, the most important, it can make your code break in several different ways.