# Converting continuos stock data in OHLC (Open, High, Low, Close) in JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

I have a continuous stream of data in below format, which I want to convert into Open, High, Low and Close based on defined time slices like 5 mins, 10 mins, 30 mins etc.. At the same time the buy_quantity and sell_quantity should also be aggregated according to choosen time slice.
What is the most efficient way to do this in Javascript on a continous stream of live data coming from websocket. 
To add to complexity, I have atleast 50 different stock codes or instrument_token coming in.
Ideal solution would be something like what is available in panda package of python - here is an example https://www.quantinsti.com/blog/tick-tick-ohlc-data-pandas-tutorial/

```
{ 
    "_id" : "Q6GinQQKKnfA7FrAT", 
    "instrument_token" : NumberInt(11552514), 
    "last_price" : 10711.8, 
    "buy_quantity" : NumberInt(714225), 
    "sell_quantity" : NumberInt(488775), 
    "buySellRatio" : 1.4612551787632346, 
    "timestamp" : "2018 07 03 07:54:52", 
    "oi" : NumberInt(20539500), 
    "oi_day_high" : NumberInt(20539500), 
    "oi_day_low" : NumberInt(19809750)
}
{ 
    "_id" : "Dwez3LuqLsB6MZRnB", 
    "instrument_token" : NumberInt(11552002), 
    "last_price" : NumberInt(26329), 
    "buy_quantity" : NumberInt(185520), 
    "sell_quantity" : NumberInt(201080), 
    "buySellRatio" : 0.9226178635369008, 
    "timestamp" : "2018 07 03 07:54:52", 
    "oi" : NumberInt(2163040), 
    "oi_day_high" : NumberInt(2170680), 
    "oi_day_low" : NumberInt(2018440)
}
{ 
    "_id" : "tcDfqRPk3qs2mYmow", 
    "instrument_token" : NumberInt(11552514), 
    "last_price" : 10711.95, 
    "buy_quantity" : NumberInt(713775), 
    "sell_quantity" : NumberInt(490125), 
    "buySellRatio" : 1.4563121652639632, 
    "timestamp" : "2018 07 03 07:54:53", 
    "oi" : NumberInt(20539500), 
    "oi_day_high" : NumberInt(20539500), 
    "oi_day_low" : NumberInt(19809750)
}
```

Comment: I'd use a library for this, e.g. D3.js or even Plotly.js which includes D3.
https://plot.ly/javascript/ohlc-charts/

Comment: @carkod, right there is an example of this for time frame daily at this stackoverflow question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42064703/convert-data-to-ohlc-open-high-low-close-in-javascript . But this is on data in DB, how to do this on live data?

Comment: do you mean something like this? https://plot.ly/javascript/streaming/#auto-examples

Comment: Your question is about `JavaScript`,That looks like a solution in the browser. In that case, is it OK for a user to wait a long time before he/she can see values for e.g. subsequent 30 minutes?

Comment: @PaulH, No we start showing the values like but aggregate and create a new candle as soon as the 30 minutes is over, similar to how you see the stock codes on google finance or yahoo or any other charting platform

Comment: @carkod, yes but show live value till we aggregate for 30 mins..

Answer (score 1):

There are two parts:
1. consolidating the data
2. display the data in a graph

For consolidating the data, an efficient data structure could be like the following:

```
data.slice.roundedtime.id
```

In this way you do not have to search with loops but you can address each remembered value instead as you go through your input data.

```js
{
  "5": { // this line once, for all 5 minutes increments
    "2018 07 03 07:50:00": { // this line each 5 minutes
      "Q6GinQQKKnfA7FrAT": { // this line for each 5 minutes each ticker 
        "volume": 123,
        "high": 20539500,
        "low": 19809750
      },
      "SecondTicker": {
        "volume": 12,
        "high": 1234,
        "low": 123
      }
    },
    "2018 07 03 07:45:00": {
      "Q6GinQQKKnfA7FrAT": {
        "volume": 123,
        "high": 20539500,
        "low": 19809750
      }
    }
  },
  "15": { // this line once, for all 15 minutes increments
    "2018 07 03 07:45:00": {
      "Q6GinQQKKnfA7FrAT": {
        "volume": 123,
        "high": 20539500,
        "low": 19809750
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The quantity of data is not an issue for a browser. Per 24 hours that the browser page is running and not refreshed, we have: 24 hours * (2 + 6 + 12) slices * 50 different quotes = 24000 records.

The 15 and 30 minutes aggregation could be computed instead of remembered. That is a detail.

Comment: But , how to arrive at this with live data? or should I first save in DB and then run a program/function to get the desired data structure

Comment: A DB is only needed if you need te remember and sort big quantities of data. That does not seem the case here.