# Convert tick data to 1 minute OHLC (Open, High, Low, Close) in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, trading

Similar to [create an OHLC data from Date, time, price using Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42064703/convert-data-to-ohlc-open-high-low-close-in-javascript), how does one take the theory of converting basic trade data to OHLC (or Open, High, Low, Close) and apply it to generating 1 minute OHLC? Beside that, I also have problem adapting epoch timestamp to ISODate with the provided code.

```
var data = [{
    "tid": 283945,
    "date": 2018-08-02T04:24:53Z,
    "amount": "0.08180000",
    "price": "501.30"
}, {
    "tid": 283947,
    "date": 2018-08-02T04:24:53Z,
    "amount": "0.06110000",
    "price": "490.66"
},
...
];

function convertToOHLC(data) {
    // What goes here?
}
convertToOHLC(data);
```

Here is the fiddle for previous code: https://jsfiddle.net/5dfjhnLw/

Comment: Please post the code you have tried so far (not just an empty function), and read the advice on [how to write a good question on StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: read the comments for the C# version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created an example, according to your requirements how to convert data to ohlc:

```
function convertToOHLC(data) {
    var parsedData = JSON.parse(data),
        pointStart = parsedData[0].date,
        range = [],
        low,
        high,
        ranges = [],
        dataOHLC = [],
        interval = 60 * 1000;

    parsedData.sort(function(a, b) {
        return a.date - b.date
    });

    $.each(parsedData, function(i, el) {
        if (pointStart + interval < el.date) {
            ranges.push(range.slice());
            range = [];
            range.push(el);
            pointStart = pointStart + interval;
        } else {
            range.push(el);
        }

        if (i === parsedData.length - 1) {
            ranges.push(range);
        }
    });

    $.each(ranges, function(i, range) {
        low = range[0].price;
        high = range[0].price;

        $.each(range, function(i, el) {
            low = Math.min(low, el.price);
            high = Math.max(high, el.price);
        });

        dataOHLC.push({
            x: range[0].date + 30 * 1000,
            open: Number(range[0].price),
            high: high,
            low: low,
            close: Number(range[range.length - 1].price)
        });
    });

    return dataOHLC
}
```

Live demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/qwvrgy93/