# Tick Data to Minute/Hour OHLC Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, trading

I have a set of tick data that looks like that :

```
var data = [{
    "tid": 283945,
    "code": "0001",
    "time": 2018-08-02T04:24:53Z,
    "volume": "12000",
    "price": "501.30",
    "mode": "B"
}, {
    "tid": 283947,
    "code": "0001",
    "date": 2018-08-02T04:24:53Z,
    "amount": "1200000",
    "price": "490.66",
    "mode": "B"
},
...
];
```

And I have written code to create daily OHLC that looks like that :

```
function convertToOHLC(data) {
    data.sort((a, b) => d3.ascending(a.time, b.time));
    var result = [];
    data.forEach(d => {
        d.date = new Date(d.time).toISOString().substring(0,10);
    });

    var allDates = [...new Set(data.map(d => d.date))];
    allDates.forEach(d => {
        var tempObject = {};
        var filteredData = data.filter(e => e.date === d);
        var filteredBData = data.filter(e => e.date === d && e.mode === 'B');
        var filteredSData = data.filter(e => e.date === d && e.mode === 'S');
        tempObject.code = filteredData[0].code;
        tempObject.time = new Date(d);
        tempObject.open = filteredData[0].price;
        tempObject.close = filteredData[filteredData.length - 1].price;
        tempObject.high = d3.max(filteredData, e => e.price);
        tempObject.low = d3.min(filteredData, e => e.price);
        tempObject.volume = d3.sum(filteredData, e => e.volume);
        tempObject.bVolume = d3.sum(filteredBData, e => e.volume);
        tempObject.sVolume = d3.sum(filteredSData, e => e.volume);
        result.push(tempObject);
    });
    return result;
};
```

However, I am living in a country where not every single minute are traded, hence some minute maybe empty. Yet, It may still be valuable to record them. Beside that, the trading hour is 9:30 - 12:30 and 14:30 to 17:30. How can I create OHLC for each minute of the trading hour with or without transaction.

Please check [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51803034/convert-tick-data-to-1-minute-ohlc-open-high-low-close-in-javascript), I apologise for not asking clearly previously. Thanks for your time!

Comment: It looks like you have simply copied the code from an answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42064703/convert-data-to-ohlc-open-high-low-close-in-javascript and want someone to write the rest for you. Please attempt to write some code yourself before asking for help.

Answer (score 2):

Efficiency is no matter when you're writing a small scale application. Now it matter. New solution avoided looping the data too many times. Now it's as fast as lightning.

```
function convertToOHLC(data) {
    var code = data[0].code;
    data.sort((a, b) => d3.ascending(a.time, b.time));
    var result = [];
    data.forEach(d => {
        d.date = new Date(d.time).toISOString().substring(0,10);
    });

    var allDates = [...new Set(data.map(d => d.date))];
    allDates.forEach(d => {
    var minuteCounter = 0;
    var hourCounter = 9;
    var halfTime = new Date(new Date(d).setHours(12,30));
    var halfTimeBegin = new Date(new Date(d).setHours(14,30));
    var fullTime = new Date(new Date(d).setHours(17,00));
    while ( new Date(new Date(d).setHours(hourCounter,minuteCounter)) < fullTime) {
        if (new Date(new Date(d).setHours(hourCounter,minuteCounter)) < halfTime ||
            new Date(new Date(d).setHours(hourCounter,minuteCounter)) >= halfTimeBegin) {
            var currentTime = new Date(new Date(d).setHours(hourCounter,minuteCounter));
            var nextMinute = new Date(new Date(d).setHours(hourCounter,minuteCounter));
            nextMinute.setMinutes(nextMinute.getMinutes() + 1);
            var tempObject = {};
            var filteredData = [];
            var filteredBData = [];
            var filteredSData = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                if (data[i].time >= currentTime && data[i].time <= nextMinute) {
                    filteredData.push(data[i]);
                    if (data[i].mode === 'B') {
                        filteredBData.push(data[i]);
                    } else if (data[i].mode === 'S') {
                        filteredSData.push(data[i]);
                    }
                } else {
                    break;
                }
            }
            var matchedLength = filteredData.length;
            data = data.splice(matchedLength);
            tempObject.code = code;
            tempObject.time = currentTime;
            tempObject.open = filteredData[0] ? filteredData[0].price : 0;
            tempObject.close = filteredData[filteredData.length - 1] ? filteredData[filteredData.length - 1].price : 0;
            tempObject.high = d3.max(filteredData, e => e.price) || 0;
            tempObject.low = d3.min(filteredData, e => e.price) || 0;
            tempObject.volume = d3.sum(filteredData, e => e.volume) || 0;
            tempObject.bVolume = d3.sum(filteredBData, e => e.volume) || 0;
            tempObject.sVolume = d3.sum(filteredSData, e => e.volume) || 0;
            result.push(tempObject);
        }

        if (minuteCounter == 59) {
            hourCounter += 1;
            minuteCounter = 0;
        } else {
            minuteCounter += 1;
        }
    }

    })
    return result;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

As much as I hate to answer my own question.

```
function convertToOHLC(data) {
    var code = data[0].code;
    data.sort((a, b) => d3.ascending(a.time, b.time));
    var result = [];
    data.forEach(d => {
        d.date = new Date(d.time).toISOString().substring(0,10);
    });

    var allDates = [...new Set(data.map(d => d.date))];
    allDates.forEach(d => {
    var minuteCounter = 0;
    var hourCounter = 9;
    var halfTime = new Date(new Date(d).setHours(12,30)); // Market close for lunch
    var halfTimeBegin = new Date(new Date(d).setHours(14,30)); // Market reopen
    var fullTime = new Date(new Date(d).setHours(17,00)); // Market close for the day
    // Generate every minute for the day and populate them with data
    while ( new Date(new Date(d).setHours(hourCounter,minuteCounter)) < fullTime) {
        if (new Date(new Date(d).setHours(hourCounter,minuteCounter)) < halfTime ||
            new Date(new Date(d).setHours(hourCounter,minuteCounter)) >= halfTimeBegin) {
            var currentTime = new Date(new Date(d).setHours(hourCounter,minuteCounter));
            var nextMinute = new Date(new Date(d).setHours(hourCounter,minuteCounter));
            nextMinute.setMinutes(nextMinute.getMinutes() + 1);
            var tempObject = {};
            var filteredData = data.filter(e => e.time >= currentTime && e.time <= nextMinute);
        filteredData.forEach(f => data.splice(data.findIndex(e => e._id === f._id),1)); // Tries to improve performance by removing unused data
            var filteredBData = data.filter(e => e.time >= currentTime && e.time <= nextMinute && e.mode === 'B');
            var filteredSData = data.filter(e => e.time >= currentTime && e.time <= nextMinute && e.mode === 'S');
            tempObject.code = code;
            tempObject.time = currentTime;
            tempObject.open = filteredData[0] ? filteredData[0].price : 0;
            tempObject.close = filteredData[filteredData.length - 1] ? filteredData[filteredData.length - 1].price : 0;
            tempObject.high = d3.max(filteredData, e => e.price) || 0;
            tempObject.low = d3.min(filteredData, e => e.price) || 0;
            tempObject.volume = d3.sum(filteredData, e => e.volume) || 0;
            tempObject.bVolume = d3.sum(filteredBData, e => e.volume) || 0;
            tempObject.sVolume = d3.sum(filteredSData, e => e.volume) || 0;
            console.log(tempObject);
            result.push(tempObject);
        }

        if (minuteCounter == 59) {
            hourCounter += 1;
            minuteCounter = 0;
        } else {
            minuteCounter += 1;
        }
    }

    });
    return result;
};
```

However, it's extremely slow hence if anyone has idea to speed it up please comment below. Thanks!